# Are any major applications using Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm investigating the use of Entity Framework in an upcoming project, but I have some concerns about the maturity and market adoption of the product.  Are there any high profile web sites or applications using the product?  Are there any significant open source projects that have picked it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually ended up talking to a person on the EF team at MS.  He pointed me to some case studies that are on their website.  Best info I could find on this subject.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff625830.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SO is built on top of LinqToSql, which shows that LinqToSQL is quite mature. LinqToSql has more or less been superseded by EF in .NET 4.0, so I don't think you can really go wrong with EF.

We've also been been running a commercial website based on LinqToSQL and am currently in the process in moving to EF.

Comment: Interesting.  Tells me a lot about LinqToSQL but not much about EF.  Out of curiosity, how painful is the transition from L2S to EF?

Comment: I'll be able to tell you in a few days. I've only just started refactoring yesterday evening. Since the data layer in my app provides quite a bit of functionality in terms of enforcing read / write access and facilitating unit testing it's a lot of code to change.